# Problem of different PHP versions reported

Tags: php

I have upgraded to PHP 5.3 on a development machine (Windows 7 box).

php-v shows

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2010 20:36:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

However, phpinfo.php shows that the version on the machine is: 5.2.14 as shown
[image: dump from phpinfo page]

The loaded configuration file **rightly** loads the correct php.ini file for 5.3
The configuration file (php.ini) Path **wrongly** reads: C:\Windows - I don't install PHP on the said path. I have however done a recursive search of PHP folders and files within that file but the search turned up nothing.

Applications seem to use the settings reported by the phpinfo and not by php -v or php -m or php -i (or else).

Apart from deleting the PHP folder and starting from scratch (which I have done), and ensuring that Apache points to the right PHP dir using PHPINIDir, what could I possibly do to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Hello
>
> You should also update apache php
>   module

---

@soju - that fixed it, thanks, but I thought I'd make this a little clearer for others.

Apache requires the php module to serve php files. On Windows it comes as a .dll file. This would be called: php5apache2_2.dll - located within your php folder. Strangely though, during upgrading the php folder with a newer version, you may find out that apache still uses the old php module file. So while php -v correctly reports the new version, Apache still looks at the old php module (reported by phpinfo). To find out what module version you have, you could: right-click on the .dll file > select properties -> view the details tab. Or just hover on the file.

[image: details screen of php5apache.dll file]

If this version is not what you want, you might want to hunt for a newer version and replace it. Good idea to back up first. Also, the php5apache.dll file works with and requires the file: php5ts.dll - so ensure these files are the same versions.

With your httpd.conf file with the directive:

```
LoadModule php5_module "\path to\php5apache2_2.dll"
```

You may restart apache and smile!

Comment: See the line reading like "LoadModule php5_module C:\path\to\php.dll" in your httpd.conf.

Comment: Thanks, if  what you mean by updating the Apache's php-module is what @rik said, the line reads: LoadModule php5_module "C:/applications/php/php5apache2_2.dll" - pointing rightly to the dll file.

Comment: Oh yes, Apache has been restarted several times but phpinfo keep reporting the wrong settings. Ideas please?

Comment: It should be noted that while the php folder contains a **php5ts.dll** file, the one that needs to be updated is located in the Apache/bin/ folder. That is - copy the file from the PHP directory to the Apache/bin/ directory and restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

Your command line (CLI) php is an other version than the one used for Apache. Check also that both use the same php.ini. When you call on your Windows machine

```
c:\path\to\php\php.exe -v
```

or

```
c:\path\to\php\php-win.exe -v
```

and

```
c:\path\to\php\php-cli.exe -v
```

They all can return different versions. Often this happens when upgrading to a new WAMP version and forgetting to delete the old versions. I'm sure you will find the executable PHP binary which matches the same version. It is also save to use the php.exe or php-win.exe instead the php-cli.exe on Windows.

Comment: Thanks powtac, but actually, it is my command line (CLI) PHP that is the newer version. I have previously run the php -v commands to show that. However I have re-run it as well as the php-win and php-cli alternatives. All return the version as 5.3.3 - which again is the correct one. Apparently, the problem comes up when Apache comes into the picture to serve up pages. It seems to be looking elsewhere for PHP settings.

Comment: Then you have to upgrade the Apache module as soju said. You cannot change the module by changing something in the configuration. You have to physically upgrade the Apache PHP module.

Comment: you may mean WAMP (SERVER) rather than WINAMP ;)