# phpinfo() is not showing correct version in the browser

Tags: linux, version, php

I am faceing a problem. The problem is : I have installed php 5.1 on my redhat linux server. then call phpinfo() in my browser. that shows php version 5.1, But after that I have install php 5.4 then calling again phpinfo() but still it shows php version 5.1 but it should be 5.4. any suggestion warmly acceptable

Comment: are you _100%_ sure it installed correctly?

Comment: probably that would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992486/problem-of-different-php-versions-reported

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo() doesn't lie; your server is running 5.1. The installation must not have succeeded; make sure you reconfigured your server to use the new version of PHP instead of still using the old one.

Comment: when i use php -v command it returns the version 5.4 but when i use the command rpm -qa | grep -i php ... it returns the packages of 5.1

Comment: The problem then doesn't seem to be with PHP 5.4 but with your web server. You still have PHP 5.1 installed and your web server is still using it. I don't know what web server you're using, but you need to change its configuration to use the new PHP installation.

Comment: So then the PHP configuration details will be in httpd.conf

Comment: where should i change actually?