# Vagrant uses old php version

Tags: php, vagrant, homestead, php-7

Can't find this online, probably not describing it properly because I'm pretty sure I am not alone with this problem.

I have vagrant running for a few months now, with PHP 5.6. Now I upgraded to PHP 7, but when I request my `php -v` inside Homestead in Terminal it still gives me version 5.6.

When I request my PHP version with this snippet `<?php phpinfo() ?>` inside a webpage I DO get version 7.

Is this normal or am I forgetting something?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**
I have version 7.0 in my vagrant ssh right now. But apperently there is a different environment for ssh, ftp, code, ...
How do I set all of these versions to the same (obviously the latest 7.0 version)

Comment: Check `whereis php` you probably have still the old PHP laying around somewhere.

Comment: This returns `/usr/bin/php`. No version number behind it. How do I check which version is active or how do I active version 7.0

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992486/problem-of-different-php-versions-reported

Comment: @kevinseda not sure if this is the same, I use vagrant/homestead. Don't have enough knowledge to say this is different or not from apache..

Comment: @Mario I'll update my question.

Comment: You have to tell apache to use the new version of php aswel, it doesnt happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and if it's the right path of php7 you can use php7.0 instead of php

```
/usr/bin/php7.0 -v
```

Comment: I only have `/usr/bin/php`, not `/usr/bin/php7.0` ... ?

Comment: Use find on youre terminal to find youre php7.0 path